# Access error when saving query

Tags: ms-access, path

I am trying to save an Access query with the following statement.

```
INSERT INTO FOO( DES_MOTIVO, DES_TIPO, DES_SUBTIPO, 
                 AGRUPACIÓN, SEMANA, CuentaDeCOD_ACCION_CLIENTE ) 
IN 'C:\Users\BAR\Desktop\03. Hola\DB STATIC INTERACCIONES MES.accdb'
```

I am getting an error when saving the query, saying the path is incorrect. Testing the path, i found out that the culprit is the period+whitespace in "03.  Hola". Deleting the whitespace fixed the issue and the query saves properly.

Is there a way to escape the period so that access accepts the save path with period + whitespace?

Thank you in advance,

Nega.

Comment: What is your exact command? i.e. how do you save a query in an .accdb? And have you tried with actual backslashes \ instead of / ?

Comment: I am using the ms-access sql editor window. I right-click the tab and save. I have tried with backlashes and / , // , /// with no success. I am using Office 2013.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, or Access 2013 behaves differently than 2010 here. You have a query open in SQL view? And then you do what exactly? How/where are you entering a path? In Access 2010 I can save the current query object only in the current database when it's open in design or SQL view.

Comment: Totally my bad. I forgot to add i am trying to execute the following statement : INSERT INTO FOO ( DES_MOTIVO, DES_TIPO, DES_SUBTIPO, AGRUPACIÓN, SEMANA, CuentaDeCOD_ACCION_CLIENTE ) IN 'C:\Users\BAR\Desktop\03. Hola\DB STATIC INTERACCIONES MES.accdb'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible with SQL or VBA code.

Fun fact: You can do it in the query designer by setting the `Destination database` setting of the query properties. Set your path, the query can be saved and executed (and it works!).

But switch to SQL view and try to save: you get the "invalid bracketing" error. Same when trying to set the SQL from VBA.

And the `DestinationDB` property that the help file mentions isn't available via code. It seems to be derived from the IN clause.

So your database will have to moved to a better path. Or, if it's single user, copy to temp path, run the INSERT, copy back.

See also: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/132184

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *quotes* around the path:

```
"INSERT INTO FOO( DES_MOTIVO, DES_TIPO, DES_SUBTIPO, AGRUPACIÓN, SEMANA, CuentaDeCOD_ACCION_CLIENTE ) IN '""C:\Users\BAR\Desktop\03. Hola\DB STATIC INTERACCIONES MES.accdb""'"
```

But why do you maintain such weird folder names as "03. Hola"?

Indeed on the Desktop, you should be able to create a simpler folder name.

Comment: The desktop file is just an example where i could reproduce the error. These obnoxious folder names where probably assigned by someone who didn't understand the extent of the problems it could cause. The folder hierarchy is used by other systems so there is no chance it can be changed. Thanks for the answer, i will try that.

Comment: I get the same error. I can't copy the text and it is in spanish. The help button takes me here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj681163(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Too bad. I'm not sure what the "Invalid bracketing" means in this context. Also. I was in doubt of the syntax, but if it runs when you remove the space, it must be all right. Would it be possible for you to (temporary)  link the table from the desktop database? That would turn your query into a very normal insert query.